# Get class __init__ arguments before initialization

Tags: python, class, initialization, arguments

I am parsing arguments from a text file, and I would like to assign them to the right classes (to initialize objects).
Now, I would like to do this in a "smart" way, that is to only pass an argument to the class if this class can indeed support it.

**How can I "ask" a class what arguments it accepts before initializing an object?**

This is some pseudocode for what I want to achieve:

```py
> args_class = Class.magic_get_arguments()
> args_class
['a', 'b']
> args_all_classes # already available
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
> args_to_pass_to_class = set(args_class) & set(args_all_classes)
# then use only args_to_pass_to_class when initializing a Class object
```

I have tried looking at the `dir` of the class, and also of the class `__init__` but the arguments do not appear there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)

It's not clear whether you want just the names of the paramters or the type hints as well, you can find both. Assume the class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass
```

To find the names, do:

```
args_class = list(inspect.signature(A).parameters)
args_class
['arg1', 'arg2']
```

To find the type hints as well as all sorts of other info, you can iterate through the parameter values:

```
for arg in inspect.signature(A).parameters.values():
    arg.name # parameter name like before
    arg.annotation # parameter type hint, returns inspect._empty if no type hint exists
    arg.default # returns the default argument for the parameter, or inspect._empty if the parameter has no default
    arg.kind # returns inspect._POSITIONAL_ONLY if parameter is only positional and inspect._POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD if argument can be given positionally or by keyword
```

Comment: great, thanks! I have to start using the `inspect` package more. There is a typo in the first snippet `Class` -> `class` btw.

Comment: @duff18 Thanks for pointing it out, you could have edited it yourself btw.